# How do I avoid lib version conflicts installing different packages with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am a bit confused. So every package that I install expects its dependencies to be of a certain version. Some versions aren't backward compatible. So if I installed the packageB which required the libX of version 1.7 first and packageA that requires same libX of version 1.2 which is not backward compatible with 1.7 later then I am screwed. It's even worse as libX depends on libY and libZ of their certain versions too.

So how do I avoid version conflicts installing numerous packages and get exact versions of libs for each package I install?

Comment: This is called "cabal dependency hell". Welcome :)

Comment: We sort of have a solution for this called cabal sandboxes.

Comment: @bheklilr It doesn't help when you have to use `packageB` and `packageA` together. We really need some integrated notion of version in the package databases.. and imports..

Comment: @jozefg That wasn't sarcasm, it's a sort of solution, and I agree that we need a better solution than cabal 1.18 and Hackage 2.0, but it's going to be a while until we reach that point.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install them at the same time.  From a fresh base (without having previously installed any libraries) try:

```
cabal install libA libB libC
```

Slightly harder is to install them separately but manually constrain the versions with the cabal `--constraint` flag.

Comment: *"From a fresh base (without having previously installed any libraries)"* So, definitely a good use case for sandboxes.